# multi submit buttons multi checkboxes no form jquery ajax php submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 10 check boxes on a page. I have a "check all" button, works perfect.

I have 4 submit buttons - 2 to delete the records, and 2 to suspend the records.

The checkboxes are not contained by a form.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-warning tip suspend" data-original-title="Suspend"><span class="icon-minus icon-white"></span></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger tip delete" data-original-title="Delete"><span class="icon-remove icon-white"></span></button>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="8" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="9" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-warning tip suspend" 
data-original-title="Suspend"><span class="icon-minus icon-white"></span>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger tip delete" 
data-original-title="Delete"><span class="icon-remove icon-white"></span>
</button>
```

When a delete button is clicked, I need to send all checked boxes via ajax to a `delete_record.php`

When a suspend button is clicked, I need to send all checked boxes via ajax to a `suspend_record.php`

I know I need to do something like

```
$("button.delete").on('click', function(){
    $("input:checkbox[class=checkbox]").each(function () {

    });
});
```

But honestly at this point I am just trial and error testing code I find online. I'd rather have a clear cut answer and explanation.

Equally how would I spit this out and have php (PDO db connections) process it as an array?

Comment: And what about `<form>`?

Comment: as suggestion in my title, there is no form, this is just a piece of the code.

Comment: So add a `form` and use standard submit.

Comment: thats not possible. There is no form because these are all written in a php loop, and the loop already has a form in it, if I add a form around the checkbox, each checkbox will have its own form, and if I add the checkboxes to the existing form, each checkbox will be part of another form. There is no way to just wrap the checkboxes in a form.

Comment: Usually this is called `bad design`

Comment: really is that whats it called? You are not at all well versed in design if you think that. Its common jqeury and ajax usage to submit elements not wrapped in a form, and *gasps its also, completely valid to use all form elements outside of a form, so I would suggest you go take it up with whatwg if you think uncontained form elements are bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took my hours to get this but here we are

**the jquery/ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete').click(function(){
    var checkValues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'delete_records.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {ids:checkValues},
    success:function(data){
    }
  });
  });
});
```

The first function in the jquery grabs all the values from checkbox and sets them as a variable array - checkValues.

The second part secnds the values as an array to the php page.

**And the php:**

```
$data = $_POST['ids'];
foreach ($data as $d) {
  $query = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM sites WHERE username=:username AND id=:id");
  $query->bindValue(':username', $username);
  $query->bindValue(':id', $d);
  $query->execute();
}
```

Sets the array to a variable $data and then runs each result as a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments are confusing but it sounds like you actually have a form wrapper from what you say, so it's understandable to not have a double form wrapper. I also am not sure if this is in a grouping and this is one grouping of many, so I am going to treat it as that:

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click',function(e){
        // Stop submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get nearest grouping
        var getGroup    =   $(this).closest('.fwrap');
        // Select children based on type
        var checks      =   getGroup.find('input[type=checkbox]');
        // Fetches the action name
        var action      =   $(this).data('original-title');
        // Creates the ajax url
        var url         =   action.toLowerCase()+'_record.php';
        // This is our storage
        var saveData    =   {};
        // Loop through checkboxes
        $.each(checks,function(k,v) {
            // Save the data to array
            saveData[$(v).val()]    =   $(v).is(":checked");
        });
        // Store the action and data
        var sendData    =   { 
            action: action,
            data: saveData
        };
        // Do the ajax here using this data and url (from above)
        console.log(sendData);
    });
});
</script>
```

**Html (assumed this is only one group of many from loop):**

```
<!-- I would use a wrap here for easy selection for this grouping -->
<div class="fwrap">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-warning tip suspend" data-original-title="Suspend"><span class="icon-minus icon-white"></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger tip delete" data-original-title="Delete"><span class="icon-remove icon-white"></span></button>

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="4" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="5" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="6" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="7" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="8" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="9" />

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-warning tip suspend" 
    data-original-title="Suspend"><span class="icon-minus icon-white"></span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger tip delete" 
    data-original-title="Delete"><span class="icon-remove icon-white"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

*One note doing it this way is that it will have unpredictable results if user disables javascript and submits the form.*

Comment: thanks for attempting to answer, I ended up getting the solution myself. :)

Comment: Sounds good! Take a look at the portion of mine that will determine the url for sending via ajax. Mine is dynamic so you don't need to specifically click a class (`.delete`) to run one code or another. You can determine where to send the ajax call by the name you specify in your `data` field. Anyway glad you got it working!